# How to make ActionListener for Java Swing Button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I would like to add an ActionListener that closes the BufferedWriter. Overall, my program is saving variable values to a file. These values get read into python scripts that are run in this Java GUI. However, I cannot get the (button click) ActionListener to work. I can only get a WindowListener (for frame closing) to work.

For a WindowListener I use the following code,

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    bufferFileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

For an ActionListener, which gives error: java.io.ioexception stream closed, I use the following code:

```
setVarFileBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Save the variable values when VarFileBtn pressed
                try {
                    bufferFileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

What code should I use to have a listener identify a button setVarFileBtn has been clicked, and subsequently close a BufferedWriter? Am I missing certain Java Swing code concepts in order to make the BufferedWriter write's get saved to a file?

Comment: Are you asking for how to verify that it was indeed `setVarFileBtn` that pressed the button?

Comment: I want to do more than verify that particular button was pressed. I then want to do some action, close the BufferedWriter called bufferFileWriter. That's what I previously had to do to save all the stuff I wrote to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. My error occurred because I had two ActionListener's for the same button. The listener not shown was for writing the variable values. Once I simply added this, to the first listener:

```
try {
                    bufferFileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
```

the variable values were written to my file.

Comment: @NickClark, it is better to have separate listeners for each function. Whever, you start writing listener code using if/else statements you have a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the button that is being pressed, you need to get the action command from the event.  You can do this like:

```
new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Save")) {
            // perform save code
        }
    }
}
```

`"Save"` is whatever the name of the `JButton` is.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out, didn't catch that! @camickr